# user to tweet some info in android app

Tags: android, twitter

As i am new to android development.
me developing an app which consist of number of videos in it.If user select any video from the given list then share option will appear if user select twitter i want to tweet the name of that video to Twitter.

as i have tried to used twitter4j,jtwitter both wants consumer & secert key and they ask the user that u wants to allow that app or not.that i don't want i want after user click on twitter twitter login window should open with name of that video as a tweet after user clicks on tweet that name will be displayed as an tweet from that user.

Thx for any help.........

Comment: Not sure this is possible within the scope of Twitter API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter has two ways of authorization, one is oAuth and other is xAuth.

In OAuth the user want to authorize your application via twitter web interface, most of the applications (in mobile, desktop and web) have chose this way in twitter, and many other social networking sites.

In xAuth you can store username and password and use directly to tweet. But for that you have to get permissions from twitter to use xAuth in your application, you can not test your application if twitter has not approved your application. This is what the [official page on twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) says about xAuth procedure.

I recommend to use the oAuth way, there are many mobile applications that use oAuth. I have used oAuth via signpost library with twitter4j in some android applications.

More on twitter authorization can be found [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth_overview).

Comment: if u r having that snippet then plz provide to me i have tried with oAuth but as you said same it wll ask authorization....

Comment: if you want to avoid authorization, than its not possible with oAuth. Using xAuth is only option remaining. If you still want to go with oAuth and ready to show authorization process you can use signpost library, can be found at google code.